# Pattern matcher is not giving expected output

Tags: java, regex

I have the below code.

```
String testdata = "%%%variable1%%% is not equal to %%%variable2%%%";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\%%%(.*?)\\%%%");
Matcher m = p.matcher(testdata);
String variables = "";
int i = 0;
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
    variables=m.group().replaceAll("%%%", "");
    System.out.println(variables);
    i++;
}
```

I am trying to print the string inside two `%%%`.
So I am expecting below output:

```
%%%variable1%%% 
variable1 
%%%variable2%%% 
variable2
```

But the actual output is:

```
%%%variable1%%%
variable1
variable2
variable2
```

Why is it so? What is the problem with this?

Comment: What if you remove `i++` and use `group(0)`?

Comment: @npinti : It worked. Thanks. :)

Comment: Had there been one more variable, there would have been error..

Answer (score 4):

You need to remove `i`. There is no need of it

```
while (m.find()) {
      System.out.println(m.group());
      String variables=m.group().replaceAll("%%%", "");
      System.out.println(variables);
}
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/j7dxnI)**

You don't also need `replaceAll` because what you require is already in first capturing group

```
while (m.find()) {
     System.out.println(m.group());
     System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/0Sy11v)**